# What is non-trivial consistency in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

There are two parts to this question:

1. How do I determine what is trivial and non-trivial in FOL? I saw several examples in linear algebra, but not in FOL.
2. What does it mean to be non-trivially consistent? I understand consistency, and am hoping this will be made obvious by answering #1.

Thank you.

Comment: "non-trivial consistency" is not a standard term. Can you tell anything about the context where you saw it? If someone said it, they must have meant something.

Comment: Thanks @CarlMummert. I have a set of axioms and am suppose to determine whether they are 'non-trivially' consistent or inconsistent. If it's not a standard term, perhaps the question is simply asking to check whether they are consistent or not. Does sound right?

Comment: If I were reading that (or writing it) I would probably take that to mean "consistent but not tautological".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Sigma$ is an inconsistent set of sentences just in case, for some $\varphi$, $\Sigma$ entails both $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$.

Suppose for some $\varphi$, $\Sigma$ already contains both $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$ as members. Then, quite trivially, $\Sigma$ is inconsistent -- we need do no real work to show that, we don't need to derive any new consequences from premisses in $\Sigma$. In such a case, it is natural to say that $\Sigma$ is *trivially* inconsistent. When $\Sigma$ is inconsistent but does not already contain a pair of the form $\varphi$, $\neg\varphi$, then we can say that $\Sigma$ is *non-trivially* inconsistent.

That isn't standard jargon, but it is entirely natural, and I imagine is all that is intended here.

Comment: Good answer. $\!\;$

Comment: @PeterSmith, is it enough to say that if the sentence contains φ and ¬φ, it is trivial? I'm struggling with the subjectivity of the word.

Comment: (i) It isn't the sentence, it is the set of sentences $\Sigma$ which contains the contradictory pair. And (ii) there is nothing subjective about whether, relative to a given proof system, it requires more than two steps (exhibiting members of $\Sigma$) to show that $\Sigma$ entails a contradictory pair of wffs.

Comment: @PeterSmith, that clarified it. Thanks!